# @import doesn't work for "remote URL" while works for "local URL"

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to import fonts stylesheet (generated by FontSquirrrel webkit Generator) using `@import`.

Works with:

```
<style type="text/css">
       @import url(Proxima/stylesheet.css); /*local*/
        a{margin:0;padding:0;border:none;}  

  @media screen {
    .webfont {
       font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
      .webfont1 {
       font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltlight', arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Doesn't work with:

```
<style type="text/css">
       @import url(https://0bf0007020cb4f97394dbf39c4e66e8f9ffcebff.googledrive.com/host/0B5Ymj7It1uz4SkUyZ3hpRVV0Nlk); /*Remote*/
        a{margin:0;padding:0;border:none;}  

  @media screen {
    .webfont {
       font-family: 'proxima_nova_rgregular', arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
      .webfont1 {
       font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltlight', arial, sans-serif !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

**Update:**

As @Vinky suggested the idea of bypassing the @import and putting the CSS inside HTML: here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/m1yf78bg/)

**P.S:** 
`@import` is used at the top of webpage.

Can't use `<link>` tag because of compatibility issues as it will be an Email Signature.

Answer (score 2):

Your e-mail client may just block external resources - as may clients from others. It's not a good idea to reference external resources from e-mails.

Use inline css styles and inline images referenced by `cid` img src.

Comment: So I should convert all my text into chunk of images? This could be marked as Spam.

Comment: No, you should not. I did not say anything about text in your e-mails. But you should not use external resources like images and CSS files. Only use inline CSS instead. For images include them as inline images as related multipart e-mail.

Comment: +1 for telling a way to include images without HTTP request. Have you any experience in Outlook2013? I am running a problem and that is, all the images are appearing as attachment in Outlook2013.

Comment: `Content-Disposition` must be `inline` and not `attachment` for the inline image parts inside the multipart. http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, how can I change to `inline` from `attachment`?
**Update:** It's Outlook2013 Client.

Sorry if I sound too naive.

Comment: An multipart e-mail has several parts. All of your inline images are some of these parts. Each part has header fields. One of these header fields is `Content-Disposition`. When an e-mail client (like Outlook) reads an e-mails part with `Content-Disposition: inline` then it does not show it as attachment, but it can be referenced by `cid` from within your html-email-part.

Comment: For learning best way maybe to create a new e-mail with Outlook and paste an image into the e-mail. Then save it as EML-File (or as MSG-File and use some converter to convert it to EML). After that open the EML-File in a text-editor.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I have to do these changes? Inside an `<img>` tag? If yes, then what is the syntax, I am fairly a newbie to this stuff, I have searched over the internet but found things which were advance to me. Maybe you can help some more?

Comment: Create an EML-File like I described above and open it with a text editor! You did not do that yet, because when you would have done that you would not ask.

Comment: I did that right after reading but I did not find any word like `attachment` or `Content-Disposition: inline`.

Comment: Okay so after saving a msg from Inbox as `.msg` and then converted into `.wml`, I eventually have found `content-disposition`, now after changing the from attachment to inline in `.eml` file how to reflect these changes in `.html` file? @Fabian

Comment: Can you please check out my this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/25412914/using-eml-for-html-mail-signature

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this as an email signature, I would suggest you include directly the CSS inside your html, instead of referencing it.

It will avoid unnecessary HTTP requests, and be more widely supported than the `@import` in mail clients.

The included FontSquirrel CSS can then be modified to load a remote font.

Comment: That won't help. Including directly CSS inside HTML still requires URL. You must be aware of the fact that `@font-face` itself uses a URL. e.g `url('mark_simonson_-_proxima_nova_regular-webfont.eot')`

Comment: I was only suggesting to bypass the `@import` because of possible browser incompatibilities. Is using the `@font-face` within you HTML `<style>` any better?

Comment: That was a nice idea to by pass, but still no gain.